# grep inverted match over string satisfying a pattern

Tags: grep, wildcards, string

I have strings per line like:

```
" … “es” completed."
" … “en” completed."
" … “fr” completed."
```

I am trying to grep inverse match of all this. That is avoid output all the lines that match with the pattern.

```
echo " … “es” completed." | grep -v " … “(*)” completed."
echo " … “es” completed." | grep -v " … “[*]” completed."
echo " … “en” completed." | grep -v " … “[\w]” completed."
echo " … “fr” completed." | grep -v " … “[\W]” completed."
```

All this grep ways still output the strings, I don't know if I need use -e as option parameter, but I am not getting the desired result

Comment: You need to use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that matches the strings, for example, `" … “..” completed\."` - not a "wildcard"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
>   Use PATTERN as the pattern. This can be used to specify multiple search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen (-). (-e is specified by POSIX .)

Yes, you should use -e. But also regex up, especially with double quotes in double quotes, dots and asteriks.

Lets say I do not want any line that ends with *completed.*

`| grep -v -e '.*completed\.$'`

- $ end of string or line
- * zero or more occurences
- . matches almost everything
- \ escape characters, in this case .

Comment: I gonna try, the problem is that there is more "completed" strings, so I really need the full regex. Also notice that the double quotes are not normal like ", are “ (probably difficult to notice)

Comment: It seems that grep -v -e " … “.*” completed\.$" work perfect ;)